# Cálculo de Fatorial em Ruby

Tags: array, ruby, recursão

Crie um script em Ruby que leia 10 números inteiros e armazene-os em um array. Depois, o script deve calcular o fatorial de cada um desses 10 números, e armazenar os resultados em um outro array, e imprimir os valores.

Não consigo acertar o calculo do fatorial e armazenamento no outro array(array2). Peço a ajuda de vocês!

**Meu código:**

```
array1 = []

for i in 0..10
  puts "Digite um numero:"
  array1.push(gets.to_i)
end

def fatorial (n)
    if(n > 1)
       return n * fatorial
    else
       return 1
    end

n = gets.to_i ()
fat = fatorial (n)
array2 = n ==1
array2 << array1

puts "Os números armazenados são: #{n} + #{array2}"
end
```

Comment: Ninguém irá fazer para você. Faça você mesmo, caso surja algum problema, aí sim venha para o stackoverflow.

Comment: Olá Brena, Compartilhe o que você tem até o momento, por gentileza.
Acredito que você seja iniciante. E algoritmos precisa ser tratado no esforço de cada um de nós. Tente! Uma hora você chega lá!

Comment: Bom dia, sou nova no fórum, esta é minha 1ª postagem. Não sabia das regras, obrigada por mim orientar. Peço a ajuda de vocês para resolver este exercício, pois quero aprender.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Só pra constar, usar recursão para calcular fatorial não é a forma mais eficiente de fazê-lo, e em aplicações reais [você não deveria usar só porque é possível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/438710/112052) (prefira a versão iterativa). Dito isso, vamos à resposta</sup>

---

Primeiramente, sua função `fatorial` tem 2 problemas:

- falta o último `end` no final para fechá-la
- quando o número é maior que 1, você deve chamar `n * fatorial(n - 1)` (pois chamar apenas `fatorial`, sem passar parâmetros, causa um erro, porque a função espera um número como parâmetro). Isto segue a definição matemática, por exemplo, `5! = 5 * 4!` - generalizando, `n! = n * (n - 1)!` (o fatorial de um número é este número vezes o fatorial deste número menos 1). Por isso a expressão deve ser `n * fatorial(n - 1)`. Se você não passar nenhum parâmetro (escrever apenas `fatorial`, como você fez), a função não tem como saber qual número usar.

Então ela ficaria assim:

```
def fatorial (n)
    if (n > 1)
       return n * fatorial(n - 1)
    else
       return 1
    end
end
```

O último `end` não deve ficar depois do `puts`, e sim logo depois do `if-else`, pois é aí que a função `fatorial` termina.

---

Quanto aos arrays, não entendi bem o que você quer fazer. Você está criando o `array1`, preenchendo com vários números e depois você não usa estes números para nada (só para copiá-los para o `array2`).

Você também está colocando o resultado do fatorial na variável `fat`, mas depois você não usa esta variável para nada.

**Se** o que você quer é criar um `array2` contendo o resultado do fatorial dos números que estão em `array1` (e este é um palpite meu, pois não está claro o que você quer), então você pode fazer algo assim:

```
array2 = []
# para cada número em array1, calcular o fatorial e armazenar em array2
array1.each { |n|  array2.push(fatorial(n)) }
```

Ou ainda:

```
array2 = array1.map { |n| fatorial(n) }
```

Com isso, cada número do `array2` corresponde ao fatorial do número que está na posição correspondente no `array1`. Por exemplo, se o `array1` tiver os números `[2, 3, 7]`, o `array2` terá os respectivos fatoriais (`[2, 6, 5040]`).

Se não for isso que você quer, [edite a sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/298412/edit) explicando melhor o que você está tentando fazer, exemplos de entrada e saída (a que você quer e a que o programa retorna), mensagens de erro que aparecem, etc.