# Uma função recursiva pode substituir while e for?

Tags: python, recursão

Em caso afirmativo, como eu poderia, por exemplo, criar uma função recursiva equivalente ao código abaixo?

```
lista = list(range(1000))
for i in lista:
       print(i)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Primeiro vou responder o título ("*Uma função recursiva pode substituir while e for?*") de maneira geral, depois falaremos sobre o código específico da pergunta.

---

> ***Uma função recursiva pode substituir while e for?***

De maneira geral, [qualquer algoritmo iterativo pode ser convertido para um recursivo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2093618) e [vice-versa](https://stackoverflow.com/q/931762). Mas só porque **pode**, [não quer dizer que você **deve** fazê-lo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/438537/112052). Recursão pode esconder algumas "armadilhas", e mesmo quando parece uma boa ideia, pode ser que a versão iterativa seja melhor.

Um exemplo clássico é o cálculo dos números de Fibonacci, que deve ser um dos mais usados para ensinar recursão. A definição dele é recursiva:

```
fib(1) = fib(2) = 1
fib(n) = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

Então é "natural" implementá-lo assim:

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        return 1
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

Mas há um problema "oculto", que não é tão óbvio à primeira vista. Se chamarmos `fib(10)`, ocorrerão as seguintes chamadas recursivas:

- `fib(10)` chama `fib(9)` + `fib(8)`

  - `fib(9)` chama `fib(8)` + `fib(7)`

    - `fib(8)` chama `fib(7)` + `fib(6)`

      - `fib(7)` chama `fib(6)` + `fib(5)`
      - `fib(6)` chama `fib(5)` + `fib(4)`
      - ...
    - `fib(7)` chama `fib(6)` + `fib(5)`

      - `fib(6)` chama `fib(5)` + `fib(4)`
      - `fib(5)` chama `fib(4)` + `fib(3)`
      - ...
  - `fib(8)` chama `fib(7)` + `fib(6)`

    - `fib(7)` chama `fib(6)` + `fib(5)`

      - `fib(6)` chama `fib(5)` + `fib(4)`
      - `fib(5)` chama `fib(4)` + `fib(3)`
      - ...
    - `fib(6)` chama `fib(5)` + `fib(4)`

      - `fib(5)` chama `fib(4)` + `fib(3)`
      - `fib(4)` chama `fib(3)` + `fib(2)`
      - ...

Repare que há várias chamadas repetidas (`fib(8)` é chamada duas vezes, `fib(7)` três vezes, `fib(6)` quatro, etc), ou seja, o mesmo valor pode ser calculado várias e várias vezes, desnecessariamente. A quantidade de chamadas cresce exponencialmente e isso torna este algoritmo bem ineficiente. Claro que você pode usar [técnicas de *memoization*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33440/112052) para guardar resultados já computados em um cache (ainda sim, haverá uma chamada para verificar se o resultado está ou não no cache), mas na verdade você só está resolvendo um problema que você mesmo criou ao usar recursão em um caso no qual ela não é a melhor solução. Um algoritmo iterativo como o abaixo:

```
def fib_iterativo(n):
    a, b = 1, 1
    for i in range(1, n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a
```

É bem mais eficiente: não há chamadas recursivas cuja quantidade cresce exponencialmente e por isso [é bem mais rápida](https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/GreenyellowOtherFact#main.py).

---

Outro problema que pode ocorrer é o [estouro de pilha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15976375). Usando outro exemplo ([citado nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/438655/uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-recursiva-pode-substituir-while-e-for/438710#comment847311_438656)), o cálculo do fatorial (outro muito usado para ensinar recursão):

```
def fat(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    return n * fat(n - 1)
```

Se eu chamar `fat(5)`, ele vai chamar `5 * fat(4)`. Ou seja, ele precisa do retorno de `fat(4)` para calcular o resultado final. Só que `fat(4)` vai chamar `4 * fat(3)`, então ela precisa esperar `fat(3)` terminar (que por sua vez, chamará `3 * fat(2)` e assim por diante).

Existe um limite para toda essa quantidade de chamadas "penduradas" esperando as outras terminarem, e quando este é estourado, ocorre um [`RecursionError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#RecursionError) ([veja aqui](https://ideone.com/nGAR3C) um exemplo).

Já usando uma versão iterativa não ocorre esse problema:

```
def fat(n):
    res = 1
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        res *= i
    return res
```

Pois agora é apenas uma chamada com um *loop* simples. Além de [não estourar a pilha](https://ideone.com/uo3anZ), também é [mais rápido](https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/AdeptAdventurousServers#main.py).

Então volto a repetir: embora seja possível converter qualquer algoritmo iterativo para recursivo e vice-versa, não quer dizer que você deva necessariamente fazê-lo. Há casos e casos, e para se aprofundar mais, sugiro que leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/112052) e [aqui](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/67897) (e siga os links que tem nas respostas também).

---

#### Sobre o código específico da pergunta

O seu código cria uma lista contendo os números de 0 a 999 e os imprime. Mas o que seria o "equivalente" a este código: uma função que imprime números dentro de um determinado intervalo, ou uma função que recebe uma lista e imprime todos os seus valores? Pode parecer que são a mesma coisa, mas não. Para o primeiro caso, a função recursiva nem precisaria de uma lista:

```
def imprime_intervalo(inicio, fim):
    if inicio <= fim:
        print(inicio)
        imprime_intervalo(inicio + 1, fim)

import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)
imprime_intervalo(0, 999)
```

O detalhe é que nesse caso eu tive que aumentar o limite de recursão usando [`sys.setrecursionlimit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit), já que o limite *default* estava sendo estourado. Esse é o problema do estouro de pilha (já citado acima e também na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/438656/112052)): há um limite bem menor para a quantidade de chamadas recursivas. Ao chamar `imprime_intervalo(0, 999)`, a primeira chamada precisa esperar o retorno de todas as outras 999 chamadas, e todas elas ficam "pendentes" esperando a última chamada terminar. A quantidade de chamadas pendentes é controlada pelo *recursion limit*, que pode ser consultado por [`sys.getrecursionlimit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit).

Por isso, o mesmo problema ocorre se tivermos um algoritmo recursivo para imprimir os valores de uma lista:

```
def imprime_lista(lista, i=0):
    if i < len(lista):
        print(lista[i])
        imprime_lista(lista, i + 1)

imprime_lista([ 'a', 'b', 'c' ])

import sys
# para uma lista com mais de 1000 elementos, precisa aumentar o limite de recursão
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)
imprime_lista(list(range(1000)))
```

Existe ainda uma outra alternativa, que é imprimir o primeiro elemento da lista e chamar a função recursiva passando o restante da lista (uma sub-lista contendo do segundo elemento em diante):

```
def imprime_lista(lista):
    if lista: # se a lista não é vazia
        print(lista[0])
        imprime_lista(lista[1:])

imprime_lista([ 'a', 'b', 'c' ])

import sys
# para uma lista com mais de 1000 elementos, precisa aumentar o limite de recursão
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)
imprime_lista(list(range(1000)))
```

Mas além de ter o problema do estouro de pilha, essa versão é ainda mais ineficiente, por ter que criar várias sub-listas (uma nova sub-lista a cada chamada recursiva).

---

Então, mais um vez reforço: só porque é possível converter um algoritmo iterativo para um recursivo, não quer dizer que você deva fazê-lo.

Comment: Nota que alguns problemas de dividir e conquistar são bem mais fáceis de dar manutenção com versão recursiva. Vou procurar editar [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/282793/64969) e postar a versão iterativa pra mostrar o como fica bagunçado

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Ah sim, tem casos e casos. Na resposta eu foquei nos casos em que a versão recursiva é pior, mas com certeza tem casos que é o contrário

Answer (score 8):

Se implementares recursividade para valores elevados, com mil por exemplo vai retornar um erro:

> recursion error maximum recursion depth exceeded

É uma proteção contra o stack overflow, sim. O Python (ou melhor, a implementação do CPython) não otimiza a recursão, ​​e a recursão desenfreada causa este problema. Você pode verificar o limite permitido pela recursão com `sys.getrecursionlimit` e alterar o limite de recursão com `sys.setrecursionlimit`, mas fazer isso é perigoso - o limite padrão é um pouco conservador, mas os quadros de pilha Python podem ser bastante grandes. Python não é uma linguagem funcional e a recursividade não é uma técnica particularmente eficiente. Reescrever o algoritmo iterativamente, geralmente é uma ideia melhor.

Contudo. Tens aqui um exemplo:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]

def load(i, arr):
  if i < len(arr):
    print(arr[i])
    i += 1
    load(i, arr)

load(0, list)
```

Comment: E em que tipo de caso recursão é uma técnica viável?

Comment: Tens aqui https://www.ime.usp.br/~leo/mac2166/2017-1/introducao_recursividade.html uma explicação detalhada. Os exemplos tipicos de recursividade, o calculo do fatorial, calcular combinações possível de moedas. entre outros.

Comment: @Luan https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/112052

Comment: Se achar uma linguagem com "tail recursion optimization", não estoura a pilha. Basta que a chamada recursiva seja a última coisa que a função faz. Em tese a especificação do Javascript prevê isso, mas parece que nenhuma implementação realmente aplicou.