# Realizar contagem em função recursiva

Tags: python, lista, recursão

Preciso contar quantas vezes uma comparação é verdadeira dentro de uma função recursiva, porém, não sei como fazer, pois qualquer variável de contagem será zerada quando iniciar o código.

```
def funcao(lista,x):
    i = len(lista)-1
    if lista[i] > x:
        k = 1
    if len(lista) == 1:
        return qntd #qntd = quantidade de números na lista maiores que x
    return funcao(lista[:i],x)
```

Preciso contar quantas vezes `lista[i] > x`, sem utilizar uma variável que seja declarada fora da função. No `return` eu já tentei várias contas (somas e produtos entre as variáveis da função) que me retornassem o que preciso, mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Queria entender qual foi o diferencial para a resposta aceita, uma vez que tem basicamente o mesmo conteúdo da outra que foi respondida anteriormente.

Comment: @tvdias me parecem diferentes a respostas, em especial na explicação detalhada. Conseguiria descrever mais ou menos em que parte as duas tem similaridade? Não achei semelhanças nas duas respostas não (tirando o fato de serem pra mesma pergunta, claro - é normal que alguma coisa tenha em comum). De qq maneira, como foi o Feitosafelipe quem selecionou, só ele pode dizer de fato.

Comment: Me parecem a mesma resposta, com o mesmo conteúdo, com praticamente as mesmas palavras, mas organizada em bullets. Com a adição do comentário sobre o for, que não tem relação com o perguntado, uma vez que o objetivo parecia ser "aprender" sobre recursividade. Mas que bom que são vistas de forma diferente por tantas pessoas, assim consigo ver era só uma percepção equivocada minha.

Comment: @tvdias A "parte do for" tem tudo a ver sim, pois fala sobre a ineficiência do algoritmo e o problema do estouro de pilha, que são 2 detalhes importantes que muitos "ignoram"/"esquecem" ao falar de recursão. Pra mim tem relação direta porque tão importante quanto aprender a fazer, é saber as consequências de fazê-lo e principalmente quando não usar (e tudo isso faz parte de "aprender sobre recursão") :-) De qualquer forma, editei a resposta para deixar mais claro esse ponto.

Comment: @tvdias Vale lembrar que a ideia do [pt.so] é formar uma base de conhecimento sobre programação e as respostas devem ser úteis não apenas para quem pergunta, mas para qualquer pessoa que visite o site futuramente. Por isso é importante não ficar "só" no que foi perguntado e tentar agregar conhecimento indo um pouco além (só tomando cuidado pra não desviar muito do foco, claro, mas em linhas gerais é isso) :-)

Comment: Sobretudo é um aprendizado também para quem responde. :) @hkotsubo obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: @tvdias Considerei a resposta do hkotsubo como correta pois além de responder à pergunta feita, ele explicou um pouco melhor sobre o que é recursão e qual a desvantagem de utilizar este método. A sua resposta também foi muito boa, dado o fato de que considerou como algo importante o aprendizado do assunto e não apenas a solução. Mas como a outra resposta ficou mais didática, acredito que seria melhor para outras pessoas que tiverem problemas semelhantes, pois tem a solução da pergunta e uma abordagem ampla do assunto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para entender recursão, você tem que entender recursão :-)

No caso de processar uma lista recursivamente, a ideia geral costuma ser:

- se a lista é vazia, não há o que fazer
- se não for vazia, verifico o primeiro elemento e computo o resultado
- verifico o restante da lista e combino com o resultado do primeiro elemento

No seu caso específico, a ideia então é:

- se a lista é vazia, retorna zero (pois não há o que comparar, então há zero elementos que são maiores que x)
- se não for vazia, verifico se o primeiro elemento é maior que x (se for, computo o resultado como `1`, senão é zero)
- somo esse resultado com a contagem do restante da lista

Traduzindo para Python, ficaria assim:

```
def funcao(lista, x):
    if len(lista) == 0: # lista vazia, não há o que comparar 
        return 0
    # verifica o primeiro elemento 
    qtd = 1 if lista[0] > x else 0
    # soma com a contagem do restante da lista 
    return qtd + funcao(lista[1:], x)
 
print(funcao([1,2,3,4,5], 3)) # 2
```

`lista[1:]` retorna uma sub-lista contendo do segundo elemento em diante (ou uma lista vazia se não tiver mais elementos). Sendo assim, na próxima chamada recursiva o "primeiro" elemento dessa sub-lista será na verdade o segundo elemento da lista original. Depois, será gerada outra sub-lista (cujo primeiro elemento será o terceiro da lista original e assim por diante, até que a sub-lista seja vazia, que é quando a recursão se encerra e os resultados são combinados).

Repare que o problema do seu código é que você só estava retornando o resultado do restante da lista, e faltou somar com o elemento que está sendo verificado em cada chamada.

---

Lembrando que a solução recursiva não é a ideal para este caso. Não só pela ineficiência de ficar gerando várias sub-listas, mas também porque muitas chamadas recursivas podem causar [um estouro de pilha](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3323001) se a lista for suficientemente grande, [veja aqui um exemplo](https://ideone.com/847Cae) (e repare que a lista nem precisa ser tão grande assim).

No seu caso, o mais simples é usar o bom e velho *loop*:

```
def funcao(lista,x):
    qtd = 0
    for i in lista:
        if i > x:
            qtd += 1
    return qtd
```

Ou ainda:

```
def funcao(lista,x):
    return sum(1 for i in lista if i > x)
```

Os *loops* acima são melhores porque, além de não criar várias sub-listas, não têm o problema do estouro de pilha, [veja aqui a diferença](https://ideone.com/LiixbQ).

Sei que isso pode não parecer relevante à primeira vista, pois "só" foi perguntado como fazer, porém tão importante quanto aprender o algoritmo recursivo, é entender as consequências de usá-lo, e principalmente, saber quando é melhor não usar (o que é o caso aqui). Saiba mais sobre o assunto lendo [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107657/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4282/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/438655/112052).

Answer (score 0):

Sempre fico na dúvida se devo responder este tipo de questão. Porque se dou a resposta vc dificilmente aprenderá a fazer recursividade; e, se respondo de forma "genérica", a resposta simplesmente não deverá ser aceita e ainda posso ser negativado por não dar a resposta ao problema.

Resolvi responder com algumas dicas e, de bônus, dou a solução. Se quiser mesmo aprender, diria para não olhar diretamente a solução e tentar fazer sozinho com base nas dias.

Tenho alguns "truques" para resolver esse tipo de problema. O 1o é pensar no "caso base" ou "resposta trivial". Neste caso podemos assumir que seria quando a lista é vazia, devendo retornar 0. A seguir deve-se "resolver" o problema e chamar o passo seguinte. Para esse caso, seria retornar 0 ou 1 (conforme a comparação) e somar ao próximo caso e ao próximo e ao outro, ... Entretanto, para fazer essa soma "que nunca acaba" é que usamos a recursividade e devemos garantir que o nosso caso base vai parar a recursão.

---

Dessa forma, tenho a solução abaixo. Note que, no lugar de remover o último elemento da lista, fiz a recursividade pelo 1o elemento. Sendo assim, posso ler sempre o elemento de índice 0, evitando algumas linhas desnecessárias.

```py
def funcao(lista, x):
  if len(lista) == 0:
    return 0

  if lista[0] > x:
    return 1 + funcao(lista[1:], x)

  return funcao(lista[1:], x)
```

O código acima pode ser melhorado de muitas formas, mas acredito que perderia um pouco da sua didática. Penso que essa seja a forma que facilita o raciocínio e leitura, face ao problema apresentado.

https://repl.it/repls/ScientificModestRoutine

Comment: O voto negativo poderia ser justificado?