# Aproximação do cosseno hiperbólico - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tenho um pequeno exercício pra fazer: comparar o resultado da aproximação do cosh(x) por série de Taylor com a função que tem na biblioteca do Python.

A série de Taylor do cosseno hiperbólico é:

cosh(x) = 1 + x^2/2! + x^4/4! + x^6/6! + ... + x^2n/2n!

Por enquanto, fiz o código abaixo:

```
import math

valores = raw_input().split(); n = int(valores[0]); x = float(valores[1])

def potencia(x, k):
    if k == 1:
        return x
    else:
        return x * potencia(x, k - 1)

def fatorial(k):
    if k == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return k * fatorial(k - 1)

def main():
    i = 0
    soma = 0
    while i < n:
        soma = soma + ((potencia(x, 2 * i)) / fatorial(2 * i))
        i = i + 1
    print(n, " : %6.3f = %6.3f" %(soma, math.cosh(x)))

main()
```

E fica dando esse erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "coshx.py", line 25, in <module>
    main()
  File "coshx.py", line 21, in main
    soma = soma + ((potencia(x, 2 * i)) / fatorial(2 * i))
  File "coshx.py", line 9, in potencia
    return x * potencia(x, k - 1)
```

As duas últimas linhas do erro se repetem infinitamente. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que na primeira iteração `i` vale zero, então você acaba chamando `potencia(x, 0)`. E por isso o código sempre cai no `else`, fazendo várias chamadas recursivas até que a pilha estoure.

Ou seja, ele vai chamar `potencia(x, -1)`, que cai no `else` e chama `potencia(x, -2)`, e assim por diante. Como nunca cai no `if`, nunca há um retorno da recursão, e uma hora [a pilha estoura](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3323001).

Mas no seu caso não precisa ser recursivo. E também não precisa calcular a potência e fatorial desde o início, pois cada termo já tem parte do cálculo do próximo. Então a cada iteração faça apenas os cálculos que faltam.

Por exemplo, se eu já tenho x<sup>2</sup>, só preciso multiplicar por x mais duas vezes para ter x<sup>4</sup>. Se eu já tenho 2! então só preciso multiplicar por 3 e 4 para ter 4! - então eu só preciso guardar o valor atual da potência e do fatorial e multiplicar o que falta:

```
import math

n = # ler valor de n
x = # ler valor de x

soma = 0
potencia = fat = 1
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    soma += potencia / fat
    potencia *= x * x
    fat *= 2 * i * (2 * i - 1)

print(n, " : %6.3f = %6.3f" %(soma, math.cosh(x)))
```

---

Veja mais sobre recursão lendo [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107657/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4282/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/438655/112052).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, percebi o que eu estava errando. Aprendi sobre recursão faz pouco tempo, então queria testar algumas coisas.