# Fazer uma função que calcule a seguinte soma:

Tags: python, algoritmo

S = 10/1! - 9/2! + 8/3! ... - 1/10!

```
def soma():
    fat = 1
    somar = 0.0
    for i in range(1, 11):
        fat *= i
        for k in range(i, 0, -1):
            somar += k/fat
    return round(somar, 2)
```

Cheguei a esse código mas o output é diferente do esperado(6.59)

Comment: Creio que este loop mais interno está duplicando a soma de termos. Troque `for k in range(i, 0, -1): somar += k/fat` por: `somar += (11-i) / fat`.

Comment: Me explica como o output esperado pode ser `6.59` se `10/1!` é igual a 10 ??? O resultado, certamente será maior que 10.

Comment: Percebi agora que existem sinais de adição e subtração. Fui traído pelo título da questão. Sendo assim, `6.59` faz sentido.

Comment: Gralha: `!3` -- `3!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver esta questão você pode implementar **duas funções**. Uma delas para calcular o **fatorial** do número e outra para produzir o **somatório** dos valores.

**OBSERVAÇÃO 1:** Observar a disposição da sequencia dos **sinais** de **ADIÇÃO** e **SUBTRAÇÃO**.

A sequência que nos foi passada foi: **S = 10/1! - 9/2! + 8/3! - ... - 1/10!**

Pois bem, para resolver esta questão podemos implementar o seguinte código:

```
def somar(n):
    soma = cont = 0
    for c in range(n, 0, -1):
        cont += 1
        termo = (c / fatorial(cont))
        if cont % 2 == 0:
            soma -= termo
        else:
            soma += termo
    return round(soma, 2)


def fatorial(nu):
    prod = 1
    for i in range(nu, 0, -1):
        prod *= i
    return prod


num = int(input('Digite um número: '))

print(somar(num))
```

Observe que quando executamos este código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite um número:` . Neste momento devemos digitar um **número inteiro** e pressionar `enter`.

Depois disso, o valor digitado será passado como parâmetro para a função **somar(n)**. Chegando lá, a cada iteração do bloco `for`, será calculado o termo **(c / fatorial(cont))**.

**Observação 2:** A cada iteração, o bloco `if` verificará se `cont` é par. Caso positivo, `termo` será decrementado de `soma`. Caso negativo, `termo` será `incrementado` em `soma`.

**Observação 3:** A cada iteração do bloco `for` da função `somar(n)`, será chamada a função `fatorial(nu)` que calcula o fatorial do **cont**.

Em seguida este **termo** é acumulado na variável **soma** e, posteriormente o retorno da função **somar(n)** será exibido.

---

Agora, se você preferir, pode utilizar o método **factorial** da biblioteca **math**. Desta forma, o código ficaria:

```
from math import factorial

def somar(n):
    soma = cont = 0
    for c in range(n, 0, -1):
        cont += 1
        termo = (c / factorial(cont))
        if cont % 2 == 0:
            soma -= termo
        else:
            soma += termo
    return round(soma, 2)


num = int(input('Digite um número: '))

print(somar(num))
```

Uma outra forma mais **rápida** para calcular esta soma é:

```
def somar(n):
    soma = cont = 0
    fat = 1
    for c in range(n, 0, -1):
        cont += 1
        fat *= cont
        termo = (c / fat)
        if cont % 2 == 0:
            soma -= termo
        else:
            soma += termo
    return round(soma, 2)


num = int(input('Digite um número: '))

print(somar(num))
```

**Vamos testar os códigos?**

Após executarmos ambos os códigos, podemos digitar quaisquer números inteiros e pressionar `enter`.

No caso de digitarmos os números **2**, **3**, **4** e **10** respectivamente, teremos os seguintes resultados:

```
n = 2 = (2/1!) - (1/2!) = 1.5
n = 3 = (3/1!) - (2/2!) + (1/3!) = 2.17
n = 4 = (4/1!) - (3/2!) + (2/3!) - (1/4!) = 2.79
n = 10 = (10/1!) - (9/2!) + (8/3!) - (7/4!) + (6/5!) - (5/6!) + (4/7!) - (3/8!) + (2/9!) - (1/10!) = 6.59
```

Comment: @Marco Raad, teste esta solução.

Comment: Deu certo. Agradeço

Comment: @Marco Raad, Bem vindo à plataforma! E, se a resposta resolveu seu problema, podes `ACEITÁ-LA`. [Veja aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta) como e porque aceitar. Apesar de não ser obrigatório, esta prática é estimulada no site, indicando a futuros visitantes que tal resposta resolveu o problema. E quando tiveres mais de 15 pontos de reputação, [também poderás votar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) em quaisquer respostas que jugares úteis.

Answer (score 3):

Em casos assim, você poderia ter feito o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/112052), que teria percebido facilmente os problemas do seu código: você não troca o sinal para alternar entre subtração e soma, e o loop mais interno é completamente desnecessário.

Dá pra fazer assim:

```
def soma():
    fat = -1
    total = 0
    for i in range(1, 11):
        fat = -fat * i
        total += (11 - i) / fat
    return round(total, 2)
```

E só.

---

Outras respostas sugeriram ter uma função só pra calcular o fatorial, que também funciona, mas neste caso eu acho desnecessário. Por exemplo, se no meio do cálculo você já fez o fatorial de 3, quer dizer que já multiplicou 1, 2 e 3. Depois, na próxima iteração terá que calcular o fatorial de 4, e multiplicará novamente 1, 2 e 3, para multiplicar por 4.

Ou seja, serão feitas várias multiplicações redundantes e  desnecessárias (isso acontece mesmo se usar a função pronta do módulo `math`, pois apesar dela [usar um algoritmo mais eficiente](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/mathmodule.c#L1851), ainda sim acaba tendo esse retrabalho desnecessário). Uma das respostas ainda sugere usar recursão, que torna tudo mais ineficiente ainda (sei que fatorial é muito usado como exemplo para ensinar recursão, mas muitos esquecem de mencionar que não é a forma mais eficiente de se fazer este cálculo).

No caso do seu cálculo, basta ir multiplicando o último fatorial encontrado pelo próximo número, e invertendo o sinal para que ele alterne entre a soma e a subtração.

---

Como curiosidade, segue um comparativo entre as soluções: https://ideone.com/nyUKyd - repare como a solução recursiva é mais lenta (claro que para cálculos pequenos executados poucas vezes não faz diferença, mas é importante se atentar a esses detalhes e [não sair usando recursão onde não precisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/438710/112052)).

Answer (score 1):

Espero que o código abaixo ajude:

```
def fatorial(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    return n * fatorial(n - 1)

NUMERO = 10
SOMA = True

num_dem = zip(reversed(range(1, NUMERO + 1)), range(1, NUMERO + 1))
S = 0
for num, dem in num_dem:
     fat = fatorial(dem)
     print(f"{num:5} {dem:5} {fat:7} {num/fat:.20f}")
     if SOMA:
         S += num/fat
     else:
         S -= num/fat
     SOMA = not SOMA

print(f"A soma é {S}")
```

O print trará

```
   10     1       1 10.00000000000000000000
    9     2       2 4.50000000000000000000
    8     3       6 1.33333333333333325932
    7     4      24 0.29166666666666668517
    6     5     120 0.05000000000000000278
    5     6     720 0.00694444444444444406
    4     7    5040 0.00079365079365079365
    3     8   40320 0.00007440476190476191
    2     9  362880 0.00000551146384479718
    1    10 3628800 0.00000027557319223986

>>> print(f"A soma é {S}")
A soma é 6.58544670414462
```

**NOTA**: Esta resposta foi editada, pois inicialmente eu não havia percebido que havia adição e subtração.

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 1):

Bom, sua sequencia mudou um pouco alternando soma e subtração.
Aqui você tem a demonstração do cálculo:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%2F1%21+-+9%2F2%21+%2B+8%2F3%21+-+7%2F4%21+%2B+6%2F5%21+-+5%2F6%21+%2B+4%2F7%21+-+3%2F8%21+%2B+2%2F9%21++-+1%2F10%21

Quanto ao seu código, aproveitando a característica do problema e não calculando o fatorial todo de cada vez, basta acrescentar a alternância do sinal.

```
def soma():
    fat = 1
    sinal = 1
    somar = 0.0
    for i in range(1, 11):
        fat *= i
        somar += sinal * ((11-i) / fat)
        sinal = -sinal
    return round(somar, 2)
```

Comment: Executando seu código, continuo tendo o output da sequencia sem a subtração

Comment: Corrigido. Faltou considerar o sinal na acumulação.

Answer (score 0):

Usando listas em compreensão (ou iteradores em compreensão)

```
from math import factorial as fac

print(sum((11-x)/fac(x)*(1 if x%2 else -1) for x in range(1,11)))
```