# Chamar uma função que retorna para uma anterior pode ocupar memória desnecessária?

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um sistema básico de menu no qual para ele eu defino uma função. Na "navegação" do menu principal posso acessar outro menu (no caso eu chamo a função deste outro menu) e neste tenho uma opção de voltar. Minha dúvida é: Se eu ficar indo do menu principal para o menu secundário e voltar, repetidas vezes, isto é uma forma incorreta de fazer este sistema pois consumiria memória desnecessária (já que eu apenas estou chamando um bloco de código que eu já fiz)?

```
def menu_sedundario():
    print("\nBem-vindo ao menu secundário. Digite [0] para voltar ao menu principal:\n")
    resposta2 = input()

    if resoposta2 == "0":
        menu_principal()
    else:
        print("\nInválido"\n)
        menu_secundario()

def menu_principal():
    print("\nBem-vindo ao menu principal. Digite [1] para acessar ao segundo menu:\n")
    resposta = input()
    
    #Verificação simples apenas para entender a ideia.
    if resposta == "1":
        menu_secundario()
    else:
        print("\nInválido\n")
        menu_principal()

menu_principal()
```

Comment: Os links indicados acima explicam porque o que vc fez não é uma boa (sim, vc usou "recursão", mesmo que não soubesse o nome). Em vez disso, uma alternativa melhor é usar um loop simples mesmo. Ex: https://ideone.com/tTHk2h - claro que dá pra melhorar e incrementar, mas a ideia básica não foge disso: um loop que exibe o menu atual, e de acordo com a opção digitada avalia o que deve fazer em seguida

Comment: Valeu pela informacão. Sou bastante iniciante em python e imaginei que uma solução com iteração seria mais válida.

Comment: Isso não vale somente pra Python, vale pra qualquer linguagem. Um loop costuma ser melhor que recursão pra esses - e muitos outros - casos (veja um dos links indicados acima: ["Quando usar recursão e quando usar laços?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/112052))

Answer (score -2):

sim, a função fica na memoria ate ser fechada.
veja no teste, que o erro de recursão é levantado quando se acumula

```
>>> def teste():
...     teste()
... 
>>> teste()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in teste
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in teste
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in teste
  [Previous line repeated 996 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

a solução mais simples para isso é usar loop

```
def menu():
    comando = input('entre comando:')
    if not comando:
        return 1

while 1:
    if menu():
        break
```

Comment: Entendi. Neste caso a solução que eu escrevi não é a ideal? Seria melhor associar uma classe para cada menu, por exemplo?

Comment: @RichardSatilite orientação a objetos não tem haver com isso e com certeza o conceito de de OO não foi criado para resolver problemas de pilha e memória, recomendo que leia os links: [O que é uma recursão de cauda?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184494/3635) / [Quando usar recursão e quando usar laços?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/3635) / [Uma função recursiva pode substituir while e for?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/438655/3635)